# One line-command for less and shift+F

Tags: bash, less, tail

I would like to open a file with `less` and automatically go in "tail mode" , which I usually achieve by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> when the file is already opened in "full screen mode" with `less`.

Is there a single line-command to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yess, you can pass the `F` option with the use of `+`!

---

Quote from [less(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html):

> `+cmd`
>
> Causes the specified cmd to be executed each time a new
> file is examined.  For example, `+G` causes less to
> initially display each file starting at the end rather
> than the beginning.

---

So in your case, use:

```
less +F seq.txt
```